# how to flatten nested json's in list using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have multiple nested jsons in list
list=[nestes_json1,nested_json2,nested_json3]

I need to take each nested_json and remove comma at the end and process it and load into single dataframe.
how to do it using pyspark.

I'm able to flatten nested_json individually but not in the form of list.

Comment: Please add examples of input and of output that you want.

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose you are having this type of table

[image]

Then you can try the explode function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df.select(df.name,explode(df.subjects)).show(truncateenter =False)
```

and then you can get the following results

[image]

After this you can explode that new table again and you will get the  exact formatting